# JS How to fix position collapsible element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I work with collapsible elements in my web page, so I create a collapsible button I which I have some data.

But when I press to button **"Open collabsible"** this view, at picture u can see the box in a midle page, after pressing **"Open"** this element go down, which i didn't want.

Example:

[image]

[image]

So as u can see and picture all elements at page go down. So i didn't want this. 
My code:

```js
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
                content.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('colapse').innerHTML = 'Open';
            } else {
                content.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('colapse').innerHTML = 'Colapse';
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <button class="collapsible" id="colapse">Open</button>
    <div class="content">
        Some dataSome data
        Some data
        Some data<br />
        Some data<br /> Some data<br /> Some data<br /> Some data<br /> Some data<br />
    </div>
```

Some idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

check it out..it is working like u want

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
margin-top:30%;
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 25%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left:40%;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

hope it would helpful for you

Comment: This working same, like my code, and button not visible at form

Answer (score 0):

Fix, by changing CSS file:

```
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

    .active, .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: #555;
    }

.content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```